# connectedComponentsWithStats causes memory problems in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

While I'm using connectedComponentsWithStats with python3, in some rare cases it cause memory-based problems. Outputs are like;

```
*** Error in `python': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x02752640 ***
Aborted
```

What am I doing is basically giving some source images to the method regularly. Their sizes are different but they are rectangle. My code is;

```
out, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(source_image, connectivity, cv2.CV_32S)
```

By the way, my environment is RPI3B+ with python3.5.3 and opencv version 4.1.0-openvino

What I get is, it is trying to access a not-allowed memory location. My question is why and how can I prevent it from happening?

PS:connectivity = 4

Comment: Are there lots of connected components in each image? Are the images large? Please share some data if you can. See [mre].

Comment: The image shape is 480x320. I believe there are many connected components in images but I am not sure. I work on live images, and it usually works well but when the camera starts to see crowded places like too many objects together, it sometimes fails.